# Add error bars to a barplot

Tags: r, vector, plot, bar-chart

I have two vectors. I want to make a barplot of the first vector (simple enough, right). The twist is that every element of the second vector is the standard deviation for every element of the first vector (which itself is the average of 4 other values). How can I do that?

The vectors in question:

```
-4.6521175 0.145839723
 1.1744100 0.342278694
-0.2581400 0.003776341
-0.3452675 0.073241199
-2.3823650 0.095008502
 0.5625125 0.021627196
```

I.e., how can I add the elements of the second column vector as error bars to the corresponding elements in the first column vector?

[image]

**Note:** Before you ask, yes I did search extensively on this site and did a lot of googling, but my problem is a bit more specific, i.e. what I found didn't match what I needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An implementation with `geom_bar` and `geom_errorbar` of `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=row.names(df), y=V1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="grey") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = V1 - V2, ymax = V1 + V2), width=0.6) +
  theme_classic()
```

this results in:

[image]

If you want to remove the numbers on the x-axis, you can add:

```
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

to your ggplot code.

---

Used data:

```
df <- read.table(text="-4.6521175 0.145839723
 1.1744100 0.342278694
-0.2581400 0.003776341
-0.3452675 0.073241199
-2.3823650 0.095008502
 0.5625125 0.021627196", header=FALSE)
```

---

In response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984974/add-error-bars-to-a-barplot#comment53798515_32985113), two possible solution when you want plot such a large number of bars:

**1:** Only include a selection of the axis-labels:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=as.numeric(row.names(df2)), y=V1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="grey", width=0.7) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = V1 - V2, ymax = V1 + V2), width=0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1,seq(10,200,10)), expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size = 6, angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

this gives:

[image]

As can be seen, it is not ideal to cram so many bars in a plot. See therefore alternative 2.

**2:** Create a grouping variable which you can use for creating facets:

```
df2$id <- rep(letters[1:20], each=10)

ggplot(df2, aes(x=as.numeric(row.names(df2)), y=V1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="grey", width=0.7) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = V1 - V2, ymax = V1 + V2), width=0.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=as.numeric(row.names(df2))) +
  facet_wrap(~ id, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

this gives:

[image]

Used data for the two last examples:

```
df2 <- data.frame(V1=sample(df$V1, 200, replace=TRUE),
                  V2=sample(df$V2, 200, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Many thanks to Jaap and Stephan. What if I were to read in the values from a file (because that's actually where they come from). The file has no headers. I do x=read.table('some.file') and I now need to pass the two vectors in question (x$V1,x$V2) to ggplot. How can I do that?

Comment: One last question Jaap, how can I add the vector element number (starting counting from 1) on the X axis?

Comment: I have around 190 data points. Is there any way I can make the numbers, as printed on the X axis, smaller, so that they don't overlap?

Comment: @Stefan in order to decrease the needed space for the numbers, you can use `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6, angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))`

Comment: Oooooopppsss, sorry, missclick.

Comment: Jaap, I tried using theme(), but it seems the number of elements is too big, so they wrap around the axis. I see number 100 in the beginning of the axis.

Comment: Once again, MY HAT DOWN TO YOU, MY GOOD SIR. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 16):

I personally like `arrows()` best for this kind of graphic:

```
df <- data.frame(bar = c(-4.6521175, 1.1744100, -0.2581400,  -0.3452675, -2.3823650, 0.5625125),
error = c(0.145839723, 0.342278694, 0.003776341, 0.073241199, 0.095008502, 0.021627196))

foo <- barplot(df$bar,ylim=c(-6,2),border=NA)
arrows(x0=foo,y0=df$bar+df$error,y1=df$bar-df$error,angle=90,code=3,length=0.1)
```

[image]

Two details:

1. `border=NA` in `barplot()` removes the borders around the bars, so you can actually see the error whiskers around the third bar. Since the third error is so small, the whisker lies pretty much on top of the bar border.
2. I used the `length` parameter in `arrows()` to reduce the width of the horizontal whiskers, which is especially relevant if we have larger numbers of bars. The default is `length=0.25`.

However, note that ["dynamite plots" have major disadvantages](http://emdbolker.wikidot.com/blog:dynamite). You write that your data come from just four raw points for each bar. In such a case it would almost *certainly* be better to just plot a (jittered) dotplot of your raw data.

Comment: That's genius. I never would have thought of angling the heads of an arrow to make it look like an error bar.

Comment: I have to agree, that is brilliant. One has to give credit where credit is due. But is there a way to decrease the width of the arrows? When there's too many data points the arrows overlap with each other.

Comment: @Stefan: Good point, that. I edited my answer to include the `length` parameter in `arrows()` (and prettify matters using `border=NA` in `barplot()`).