# How to avoid bar reordering in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following `data.frame`called `df1`:

```
              meanS      meanQ1     meanQ7    meanQB        SDS       SDQ1        SDQ7       SDQB
A     0.0000000  18.5097329  82.979770 112.39874  0.0000000 15.7327272  14.8470696 57.4588193
B     0.8251663   1.5863240   6.113925  13.18822  1.1669613  0.9277886   0.6524881  3.3680380
C    4.7411325  16.6099939  40.202326  65.54109  1.9964880  9.0839058  11.7395347 15.3689217
D    5.5147541  11.3603839  62.658601  52.91574  1.8887582  7.0104244   7.7074550 12.1494890
E    1.0847299  28.1761223  31.865756  24.22025  0.3728842 10.2018362   5.6468526  8.9097609
```

Where the columns are the means of 4 conditions and  the respective standard deviations (SD).

In order to generate multiple `ggplot` bar plots (one for each row), I'm doing the following (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335598/create-barplots-using-different-matrix-probably-loop-has-to-be-involved?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

```
df2 <- df1[,1:4]
library(data.table)
df2 <- data.table(t(df2), colnam = colnames(df2), df = "df2")
df2 <- melt(df2, id.vars = c("colnam", "df"))
df2[, sd := t(df1[,5:8])]

ggplot(df2, aes(x = colnam, y = value, fill = df, ymax = value + sd, ymin = value - sd)) + 
geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
facet_wrap(~variable, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y") +
geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), width=0.2)
```

My problem is that when I do this, the order of the bars is changed from (S, Q1, Q7,QB) to (Q1, Q7,QB, S).

Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217594/prevent-ggplot2-from-automatically-ordering-x-axis

Comment: Just relevel that factor...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you specifically order ggplot2 x axis instead of alphabetical order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774210/how-do-you-specifically-order-ggplot2-x-axis-instead-of-alphabetical-order)