# How to plot bar plot and error bar with x,y data in R

Tags: r, plot, errorbar

I have data in following format.

```
X        ID         Mean       Mean+Error Mean-Error
61322107 cg09959428 0.39158198 0.39733463 0.38582934
61322255 cg17147820 0.30742542 0.31572314 0.29912770
61322742 cg08922201 0.47443355 0.47973039 0.46913671
61322922 cg08360511 0.06614797 0.06750279 0.06479315
61323029 cg00998427 0.05625839 0.05779519 0.05472160
61323113 cg15492820 0.10606674 0.10830587 0.10382761
61323284 cg02950427 0.36187007 0.36727818 0.35646196
61323413 cg01996653 0.35582920 0.36276991 0.34888849
61323667 cg14161454 0.77930230 0.78821970 0.77038491
61324205 cg25149253 0.93585347 0.93948514 0.93222180
```

How can i plot error bar plot with column(bars) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1x7l.png)

where X-Axis is having X value. So each bar will be plotted at X of fixed width.

Comment: See [these examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+barplot+error+bar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add error bars to a barplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984974/add-error-bars-to-a-barplot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try answering. I am using a package called **plotly**. You can look [here](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#bar-error_y-value) for more details.

```
df <- read.csv('test.csv')
colnames(df) <- c("x", "id", "mean", "mean+error", "mean-error")
df$`mean+error` = df$`mean+error` - df$mean
df$`mean-error` = df$mean - df$`mean-error`

library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(factor(x), y = mean)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
p <- plotly_build(p)

length(p$data)

p$layout$xaxis

plot_ly(df, x = 1:10, y = mean, type = "bar",  
        error_y = list(symmetric = F, 
                       array = df$`mean+error`,
                       arrayminus = df$`mean-error`,
                       type = "data")) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(tickmode = "array",tickvals = 1:10,ticktext = df$x))
```

I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most popular approach would probably be using `geom_errorbar()` in `ggplot2`.

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(df, aes(x=ID, y = Mean)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="light blue") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean.Error, ymax = Mean.Error.1))
```

where `Mean.Error` and `Mean.Error.1` are the header names for mean +/- error you get when you try to read in your example as text.

Comment: ggplot2 i can implement but problem is i have other series like line plot and scatter plot that are difficult to merge(layout) into this plot as they are not grid plot.

Comment: @prog adding a +geom_line() or geom_scatter shouldn't be a big deal.  But that wasn't in your question.  You should accept one of these answers and then try to add the other geoms and ask another question of you still have trouble.