# How to add error bars to barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and have produced a graph, but I want to add error bars as simply as possible and I do not know how.

```
ana <- read.table(text="Infiltration    Grazing Burn
3301.145496 G   S
8165.771889 U   S
9937.833576 G   L
11576.5892  U   L
32739.07643 G   N
25923.84328 U   N", header=TRUE)
```

That is my data and below is the code I have used.

```
    barplot(xtabs(ana$Infiltration ~ ana$Grazing + ana$Burn ),beside = TRUE, col = c( "tan4", "darkgreen"), xlab = "Burn Treatment", names = c( "Long Rotation", "Burned 1954", "Short Rotation" ) , ylab = "Mean Infiltration Rate (mm/h) " , legend = c( "Grazed", "Ungrazed"), args.legend = list(title = "Graze Treatment", x = "topright", cex = .7), ylim = c(0, 35000)  )
```

as I am new to R please explain as simply as possible!

Comment: I am aware the table I have added is not formatted correctly, I do not know how to edit this

Comment: Just format it like code, i.e. select it and then click the {} button.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately it isn't really that simple to add error bars in a base R plot. I think it's a *lot* easier to do it with ggplot2. That's an R package that you can use to make plots. Try this tutorial: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Also, your example data does not have any values that could be used for the length of the error bars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add error bars to a barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984974/add-error-bars-to-a-barplot)

Comment: How have you calculated the errors? There are no errors on your data. And there's no "error" in just a single number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic `ggplot2` implementation of what you are after

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

## Read in the q data
df <- read.table(text = "Infiltration    Grazing Burn
                 3301.145496 G   S
                 8165.771889 U   S
                 9937.833576 G   L
                 11576.5892  U   L
                 32739.07643 G   N
                 25923.84328 U   N",
                 header = TRUE)
## Add test Lower and upper bounds, trans varnames

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(ll = Infiltration * 0.9,
         hh = Infiltration * 1.1) %>% 
  mutate(Grazing = Grazing %>%
           recode(G = "Grazed", U = "Ungrazed"),
         Burn = Burn %>% 
           recode(S = "Short Rotation", L = "Long Rotation", N = "Burned 194")) %>% 
  rename(`Graze Treatment` = Grazing)

## Basic boxplot with ci's
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Burn, y = Infiltration, fill = `Graze Treatment`)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ll, ymax = hh), position = "dodge") +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(y =  "Mean Infiltration Rate (mm/h)",
       caption = "Errorbars represent ....")
```

It looks like this:

[image: Basic boxplot]

In general boxplots with whiskers are a bit hard to interpret. It might be better to use something like this..

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Burn, y = Infiltration, fill = `Graze Treatment`, col = `Graze Treatment`)) +
  geom_point(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 1), size = 3) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = ll, ymax = hh), position = position_dodge(width = 1),
                 alpha = 0.4, size = 3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  labs(y =  "Mean Infiltration Rate (mm/h)",
       caption = "Errorbars represent ....")
```

[image: Improved plot]

*Note: If you have the raw data from which you generated your confidence intervals you might be better served using a boxplot (with `geom_boxplot`), a violin plot (with `geom_violin`) or even a ridge plot (`ggridges:geom_density_ridges`).*

**Some possible extensions**

If the underlying data is available we can do much better. There are several options, which one you pick comes down to your use case and the size of your data.

First lets generate some sample data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

## Read in the q data
df <- read.table(text = "Infiltration    Grazing Burn
                 3301.145496 G   S
                 8165.771889 U   S
                 9937.833576 G   L
                 11576.5892  U   L
                 32739.07643 G   N
                 25923.84328 U   N",
                 header = TRUE)
## Generate and clean some sample data
df <- df %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  mutate(Infiltration = map(Infiltration, function(x) {
    tibble(Infiltration = rnorm(n = 1000, 
                                mean = x, 
                                sd = 0.1 * x),
           id = 1:1000)
    })) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  mutate(Grazing = Grazing %>%
           recode(G = "Grazed", U = "Ungrazed"),
         Burn = Burn %>% 
           recode(S = "Short Rotation", L = "Long Rotation", N = "Burned 194")) %>% 
  rename(`Graze Treatment` = Grazing)
```

Now lets make some plots .

1. The underlying data with jitter.

[image: scatter plot]

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Burn, y = Infiltration, fill = `Graze Treatment`, col = `Graze Treatment`)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitterdodge(), alpha = 0.1) +
  theme_minimal() +
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  labs(y =  "Mean Infiltration Rate (mm/h)",
       caption = "Errorbars represent ....")
```

2. Boxplots

[image: boxplot of the underlying data]

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Burn, y = Infiltration, fill = `Graze Treatment`, col = `Graze Treatment`)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.4) +
  theme_minimal() +
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  labs(y =  "Mean Infiltration Rate (mm/h)",
       caption = "Errorbars represent ....")
```

3. Violin plots

[image: Violin plot]

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Burn, y = Infiltration, fill = `Graze Treatment`, col = `Graze Treatment`)) +
  geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), alpha = 0.4) +
  theme_minimal() +
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  labs(y =  "Mean Infiltration Rate (mm/h)",
       caption = "Errorbars represent ....")
```

4. Points with mean, 1 and 2 standard deviations

[image: Mean with 1 and 2 standard deviations]

```
df %>% 
  group_by(`Graze Treatment`, Burn) %>% 
  summarise(
         mean = mean(Infiltration),
         sd = sd(Infiltration),
         lll = mean - 2 * sd,
         ll = mean - sd,
         hh = mean + sd,
         hhh = mean + 2*sd) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Burn, y = mean, fill = `Graze Treatment`, col = `Graze Treatment`)) +
  geom_point(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 1), size = 3) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = lll, ymax = hhh), position = position_dodge(width = 1),
                 alpha = 0.4, size = 3) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = ll, ymax = hh), position = position_dodge(width = 1),
                 alpha = 0.6, size = 3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  labs(y =  "Mean Infiltration Rate (mm/h)",
       x = "Infiltration",
       caption = "Errorbars represent ....")
```

5. Both jittered points and violin plots

[image]

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Burn, y = Infiltration, fill = `Graze Treatment`, col = `Graze Treatment`)) +
  geom_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75),
              position = position_dodge(width = 1),
              aes(fill = NULL)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 1), alpha = 0.01) +
  theme_minimal() +
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  labs(y =  "Mean Infiltration Rate (mm/h)",
       caption = "Errorbars represent ....")
```

and any other summary plot overlayed with the raw data. This falls down when you have lots of data in which case one of the summary plots by itself will be better.

Comment: wow. This is amazing