# How to plot minimum, maximum, and mean in r

Tags: r, data-visualization, mean, max, minimum

I've been reading how to plot points in r, but can't find anything that matches my problem. My data is a matrix; the rows start with a column called 'site' and it is followed by three columns containing the parameters: minimum, mean, and maximum. There are four rows in the matrix, corresponding to 4 sites.

What I want is a graph that has the 4 sites on the x-axis and the three data points (min, mean max) above each site, connected by a line. The mean would be represented by a circle, while the min and max by a cross bar. Each of the means would be connected by a line. My output would look like a boxplot without the boxes and with a line connecting the means.

Can anyone help me? It seems like a simple problem but I'm stumped.

Comment: Please consider adding a minimum working example, including a matrix with data that people can immediately copy and paste into R, then flagging your question for moderator attention and requesting migration to Stackoverflow.com.

Comment: When I tried to add the matrix, it comes out as a single line. I'd love to put it in my question, but the websites formatting keeps it from being a matrix.         Site Minimum Mean Maximum
LW    24.2 27.7  31.3
Laf    22.4 29.7         37.0
Cr    23.1 30.7  38.2
GH    25.9 30.0         34.1

Comment: If your matrix is called `myMatrix`, then just type `dput(myMatrix)`. The result is something we can just paste into an R console, prefix it with `myMatrix <- `. and voilà. we have *the exact same thing* you have.

Answer (score 1):

Define a random matrix:

```
set.seed(1)

n_sites <- 4

myMatrix <- cbind(t(replicate(n_sites,sort(rnorm(3)))),1:n_sites)
dimnames(myMatrix) <- list(paste("Site",1:n_sites),c("Min","Mean","Max","n"))
```

Plot:

```
plot(c(1,n_sites),range(myMatrix),type="n",xlab="",ylab="",xaxt="n",las=1)
axis(1,1:n_sites,rownames(myMatrix))
arrows(x0=1:n_sites,y0=myMatrix[,"Min"],x1=1:n_sites,y1=myMatrix[,"Max"],angle=90,code=3,length=0.1)
points(1:n_sites,myMatrix[,"Mean"],bg="white",pch=21,type="o")
text(1:n_sites,myMatrix[,"Max"],myMatrix[,"n"],pos=3)
```

[image: plot]

[I like using `arrows()` in cases like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32985182/452096)

Comment: Now I'd like to add the sample size to the above plot. If I add the sample size as a fourth column in the matrix (call it 'n'), how do I do change the code?

Comment: I updated the answer. The key is to add text using the `text` command.

Comment: Thanx for the answer...now I'd like to have the sample size labelled "n=1", "n=2", and etc.

Comment: No need to answer me...I figured it out. Thank you again for your help.